# Or operator not working inside jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have file input. For demo, when anything else except `.png` or `.jpg` uploads, an alert message will come that says, "this file is not supported". So, I have written jQuery like this:

```
if (extension != 'png' || extension != 'jpg') {
   alert('This file is not supported');
}
```

But, it seem that it's not working. If I cut from this portion, `|| extension != 'jpg'`, function will work perfectly. What's the problem with that line?

[Fiddle Work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/9go4uwpk/)

Comment: *Every value* is either not `"png"` or not `"jpg"`. I'll check to see if there's an existing duplicate of this that clearly explains the issue and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an AND operator here, not an OR operator. If you use OR, it will always say the file isn't supported.